# How to rearrange search results in Unity dash home?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

Unity dash home currently displays results in the following order:

- Application results
- Documents results
- Downloads results
- Music results, etc

[image: Pretty Unity screenshots]

What I would like is to have the Documents and Downloads results above the application results in Dash home. Is it possible to reorder the search results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For 12.04

You can use `dconf-editor` to rearrange the search results in Unity dash home.

Install *dconf-editor* by clicking on this big button:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or by running this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then navigate to `com` → `canonical` → `Unity` → `Dash` and change the setting for `home-lens-ordering` to `['files.lens', 'applications.lens', 'music.lens']`.

[image: Dconf-tools]

If you would like to get back to the default setting, you can hit the Set to Default button on the lower right corner.

This is what you get once you adjust the setting as above:

[image: Pretty Unity dash images]

---

Alternatively, if you don't like to hunt with your mouse, you can run this command in a terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Dash home-lens-ordering "['files.lens', 'applications.lens', 'music.lens']"
```

It will order the results in the way you prefer.

To reset the setting, you run this command:

```
gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Dash home-lens-ordering
```

Comment: Do remember, I am currently lacking a working hard disk and am stuck on an old Windows system. Ill try to get VirtualBox working, though.

Comment: No hurry, I've put the bounty on layaway ;)

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS, I have nothing but webapps in com.canonical.unity, no dash ... And yes, Im on 12.04 with a working dash...

Comment: @user55822 Try the terminal method.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS, silly me, I did try it but thought it didnt work. It did, "recents" are first, although I dont have a "download" category. And it still don't show up in dconf. Weird.